# Finitely Generated $k$-algebra has algebraically independent generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

I'm working on the following problem from Dummit and Foote 15.3 Exercise 15).

Let $V$ be an affine algebraic set over an algebraically closed field $k$. Prove that for some $n$ there is a surjective morphism from $V$ onto $\mathbb{A}^n$ with finite fibers, and that if $V$ is a variety, then $n$ can be taken to be the dimension of $V$.

In particular I'm a little stuck on the second part here. If we assume that $V$ is a variety, then we get that $k[V]$ is a integral domain. It seems like we should be able to use this fact to show that some finite of generators for $k[V]$ are algebraically independent and thus have cardinality equal to that of the dimension of $V$, but I can't quite see how.

Comment: This is precisely the [Noether Normalization Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether_normalization_lemma)

Comment: @cos_dm_math21 as I understand it, the Noether normalization lemma guarantees the existence of a finitely generated sub-algebra with algebraically independent generators, but I want to show that the generators for k[V] itself (not a sub-algebra thereof) are algebraically independent

Comment: But why would that be true? I'm not sure I understand what you mean correctly, but you seems to imply that $k[V]$ is isomorphic to a polynomial ring, which is clearly not true in general.

Comment: @CaptainLama why would that not be true in general?

Comment: That would mean that all varieties are isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^n$. But they are not; what you are trying to prove is that $V$ is finite over $\mathbb{A}^n$, not isomorphic to it. So $k[V]$ is a finite algebra over some polynomial algebra, not a polynomial algebra itself.

Answer (score 0):

The (or one of the) algebraic statement of the Noether Normalization Lemma is the following:

Let $A$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra and $d$ the Krull dimenstion of $A$. Then there exist algebraically independent elements $x_1, \ldots, x_d \in A$ such that $A$ is an integral extension of $k[x_1, \ldots, x_d]$.

This result has a very beautiful translation in the language of algebraic geometry:

Let $V \subseteq \mathbb{A}^m$ be an affine variety and $n = \text{dim}(V)$. The geometric version of the Noether Normalization Lemma ensures that there exists some finite surjective morphism of affine varieties:
$$\phi : V \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^n$$

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying, but I haven't actually cleared up my confusion, just shifted the thing I'm stuck on to a version of the Noether Normalization lemma that I'm unfamiliar with. I understand from the NNL applied in the earlier part of the problem why for any affine algebraic set V there is an inejctive morphism V to A^n induced by the inclusion of the subalgebra $R\subseteq S = k[V]$ (where $R$ comes from the NLL), but in the case where $V$ is a variety, why can we take $R=S$ or in other words why are the generators of $S=k[V]$ algebraically independent?